# Enumerating all partitions induced by Voronoi diagrams for clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

a classical results by M. Inaba et al. in "Applications of Weighted Voronoi Diagrams and Randomization to Variance-Based k-CLustering" (Theorem 3)  says

> The number of Voronoi partitions of $n$ points by the Euclidean Voronoi diagram generated by $k$  points in $d$-dimensional space is $\mathcal{O}(n^{dk})$, and all the Voronoi partitions can be enumerated in $\mathcal{O}(n^{dk+1})$.

They basically divide the $d$-dimensional space into equivalence classes where two sets of center $\mu^1$ and $\mu^2$ are equivalent if they lead to the same Voronoi Diagram. Then they show that the arrangement of the $nk(k-1)/2$ surfaces

$$ \|x_i-\mu_j\|^2- \|x_i-\mu_{j'}\|^2 = 0 $$

for each point $x_i$ and two cluster center $\mu_j$ and $\mu_{j'}$ coincides with the equivalence relation from Voronoi partitions.

Next they argue that   the combinatorial complexity of arrangements of $nk(k-1)/2$ constant-degree algebraic surfaces is bounded and that this implies and algorithm with running time $\mathcal{O}(n^{dk+1})$. Unfortunately, the cited source (Evaluation of combinatorial complexity for hypothesis spaces in learning theory with application, Master's Thesis, Department of Information Science, University of Toko, 1994) I cannot find anywhere. More precisely I cannot see the two following things.

1. Where can I find a bound for the combinatorial complexity of the arrangement of $nk(k-1)/2$ constant degree algebraic surfaces and
2. How does this help me to compute the arrangement?

For 2. I found the Bentley–Ottmann algorithm, however that only works for line segments and not degree 2 polynomials. How can this algorithm be generalized?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If the typographical difference between $\|x\|$ and $||x||$ is not conspicuous enough for you, notice the difference between $\|x\|\|y\|$ and $||x|| ||y||$ (the latter coded as `||x|| ||y||`. This kind of thing is why TeX was created in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For results on the combinatorial complexity of arrangements (and other related results) a good reference is [Chapter 28](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/danhalperin/chap28-fin-idx.pdf) of *[The Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/HDCG3.html)*.
In particular Theorem 28.1.4 specifies that the combinatorial complexity of an arrangement of $n$ constant-degree algebraic surfaces of dimension $d$ is $O(n^d)$.

Within the context of the paper $k$ is considered fixed, and therefore
$nk(k-1)/2 = O(n)$.
Further, in the paper the dimension of the vector space in the proof of Theorem 3 is $dk$.
Thus, the complexity of the surface arrangement in the $dk$-dimensional vector space is $O(n^{dk})$.
Note that if $k$ were not considered fixed (but still $O(n)$), then the complexity would have been
$O((nk(k-1)/2)^{dk}) = O((n^3)^{dk}) = O(n^{3dk})$.

This answers your first question.

As for 2, the Bentley-Ottman algorithm can be generalized for any
set of $x$-monotone curves (if the curves are not $x$-monotone, a splitting pre-process is required).
The main difference from the case of line segments is to allow for
more than a single intersection between curves and also for the possibility
of tangent intersections.

This means that when the sweep-line algorithm passes an intersection point, it needs to check whether the order of the curves in the sweep-line structure should be swapped (a non-tangential intersection) or maintained (a tangential intersection).
It also needs to check for the next intersection point between the adjacent curves, if it exists (since there can be more than a single intersection point).

[CGAL](https://www.cgal.org)-The Computational Geometry Algorithm Library, implements such a generic sweep-line algorithm in its [arrangements package](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-arrangement-book).
It uses its "Traits" mechanism to implement the above requirements with implementations on circle arcs, conic sections, polynomials of any degree, and more. See the [CGAL package documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_sweep_2/index.html) for further reference.